# Pay pal integration error - Android

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, paypal

I have to integrate Paypal in my app so i got tutorials [here](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/paypal-sdk-integration-in-android-applications/) and [here](http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/integrate-paypal-in-android).

In tutorial i found that download the `Jar` and add as `library`. I cant find jar file in this link. It have aar file only.

But in the [link](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/) they said for android stdio do this :

Add the SDK to Your Project

The `PayPal Android SDK` is now available at `Maven Repository`. The latest version is available via `mavenCentral()`. Just add the following dependency from `mavenCentral()`:

```
compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.1'
```

SO My `build.gradle` file looks like :

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}


dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.1'
}
```

ERROR GETTING:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not determine artifacts for com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.13.1: No cached version available for offline mode
```

After Disabling `OFFILNE MODE AND SYNC` it takes much time . not finished the process `gradle sync`.

I cant able to integrate Paypal in android studio...
Anyone tell me what i have done wrong and how to integrate ? 
thanks.

Comment: Have you added 

compile files('libs/okhttp-3.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/okio-1.6.0.jar')
compile project(':PayPalAndroidSDK-2.13.1')

those files

Answer (score 0):

3.0.1.jar and okio-1.6.0.jar latest jar files

```
compile files('libs/okhttp-3.0.1.jar')
compile files('libs/okio-1.6.0.jar')
compile project(':PayPalAndroidSDK-2.13.1')
```

Comment: hi tq, first i need jar file for this where do i get PayPalAndroidSDK-2.13.1 and other libs

Comment: You can Download it from gitHub  


https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Android-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md

Comment: And please add    CONFIG_CLIENT_ID   from paypal account